# Email sync problem

Tags: sync, email

My corporate email sync is working to download emails. It’s able to download contacts and events, but not emails. I did the factory settings also, but even it’s not working. Could anybody reply with solution?

Comment: Not unless you provide some more details, as nobody here knows what your "corporate email sync" is.

Comment: It’s office emails...

Comment: Sure corporate mails are mostly office mails. But what system? Exchange Active Sync (EAS)? Or something else? And which app are you using on your Android device? Please don't simply say "the default one". If that's the case (and you don't know which it is), at least give some details on your device.